# How to replace bytes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, replace, hex, byte

I have two strings:

```
Dim Original_Hex_Bytes as string = "616572646E61"
Dim Patched_Hex_Bytes as string = "616E64726561"
```

Then I have a binary file and I need to search for the Original_Hex_Bytes and replace them with Patched_Hex_Bytes; I don't konw the offset where begin to write new bytes :(

How can I do this?

If needed, I also know how to convert Hex strings in bytes, I use this:

```
Private Function Hex_To_Bytes(ByVal strinput As String) As Byte()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim bytes(strinput.Length / 2) As Byte
        Do While (strinput.Length > i + 1)
            Dim lngDecimal As Long = Convert.ToInt32(strinput.Substring(i, 2), 16)
            bytes(x) = Convert.ToByte(lngDecimal)
            i += 2
            x += 1
        Loop
        Return bytes
    End Function
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Are you able to open and read a file?

Comment: The major problem with not specifying the offset is that you may change the wrong bytes if the sequence occurs more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter classes to achieve this.
But in this case, as you do not know the file structure, need to read the entire file and sweep it in search of bytes array and will be easier to use ASCII strings as aerdna and andrea.
When you know the structure of a file is more appropriate to work with data structure to manipulate its contents.